# Floating boxes when resizing window

Tags: html, css, layout, grid

I'm fighting with the unusual grid and I added some hover effects to boxes and when I'm resizing window it behaves so weird. I mean the final structure is good but why those boxes jumping in that way? I'm not uploading the code here because there are many things from other subpages and still much unnecessary code. Any suggestions how to fix it? Thanks!

[Demo here](http://alanpodemski.com/test)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the contents of your`<body>`in a single `<div>`. 
Set that div's width property like so:

```
.wrapper
{        
    width:1000px;        
    min-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The above values are given only as examples. Adjust the numbers to your liking.

Comment: hmm not sure how it can help here... The whole grid has container at some breaking points with pixels - 1410px, 1300px etc (% were killful in this layout).